# Map exporting incorrectly (all formats)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, layouts

When exporting my map the export process seems to fattens up all my shapes resulting in the exported map displaying incorrectly - regardless of format, even tried various output dpi.

This is what it looks like in Layout View [image]

And is how it exports  [image]

Comment: Have you tried Repair Geometry on that feature class that goes missing?

Comment: If your 'setbacks' datasource is a shapefile, try exporting it to a feature class, too. Incorrect geometries occuring in shapefiles (and causing 'color leaks' when the map is exported, like here) are normally not allowed in gdb feature classes